# How to get last element of particular visible div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have multiple screens present in single html page and using knockout binding , a particular screen is shown or hidden.I need to circulate tab focus in input fields , if present, in the shown div only . I have attached a small [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BYJdS/5/) as well.

1. If showPersonalScreen and showFilterScreen both are visible , with my JS code , tab event is stopping  at LABEL_FILTER_PATIENTID input field
2. If showPersonalScreen is visible , with that JS code , tab event is not stopping but my requirement is that it should stop at LOCATION input field
3. If showFilterScreen is visible , with that JS code , tab event is properly stopping input_PatientID_filter . This is because , it's the last div in the defined HTML having last input field.

Below JS code used to get last input field and disable default behaviour of tab key

```
 $('input').last().on('keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 9) {
            document.body.firstElementChild.focus();
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Knockout binding to show and hide a particular div

```
var viewModel = {
        showFilterScreen : ko.observable(true),
        showPersonalScreen : ko.observable(false)
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

So my requirement is ,there should be some generic JS code in which tab event stop in last input field of visible div and if visible div is not having any input field then tab should not work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

To find whether visible div have any input field use the below code . if length>0 refers div has input field

```
 $("#yourdivid").find("input:visible").length
```

To find the last input field use this code

```
$("#yourdivid").find("input:visible").last()
```

Comment: I am trying in this (fiddle)[http://jsfiddle.net/px3AV/4/] but here it's not working but in my old fiddle link , it's working. Can you please guide me where I am going wrong.

Comment: I got the issue with my new fiddle. It's happening because one input field is having disabled property . that's why its failing. kindly tell me how to frame jquery for finding input field which is not disabled or readonly

Comment: if(document.getElementById('your id').getAttribute('disabled'))  Returns true if element is disabled else false

Comment: $("#personal_info").find("textarea,input:visible:enabled").last() This expression worked for me...Thanks alot